# New GFCI Tamper Resistant Outlet not working

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, receptacle, gfci

Purchased a new Leviton Tamper-Resistant GFCI Outlet.  Installed it and the green light comes on, but when I plug something into it, it doesn't come on. Tried something else that I know works and still no power to it even though the light on it is green.  The reset / test buttons are very hard to press and one of them doesn't seem to be working.. Can I fix the button? Did I install it wrong?

Comment: Turn off the breaker, pull out the GFCI, and take pictures of how you wired it.

Comment: Are you sure you connected to the Lind terminals and not the Load terminals? If you are using both, try disconnecting the Load terminals and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Did you actually press the reset button then the test button and hear a click where the reset button pops out slightly, if not the receptacle may not be reset, I have big fingers and use a screwdriver to push the buttons.

Comment: Many need to be reset when first powered, even if everything is wired correctly.

Comment: Yes, GFCI outlet troubleshooting step 1 should be cycling of the TEST and RESET buttons!

Answer (score 2):

Basic trouble-shooting for GFCI/receptacle:

- Disconnect all wires.
- Determine which wires are incoming/line. Connect hot and neutral from that set (wires or cable) to the incoming/line side of the GFCI.
- Turn on the breaker and test: indicator light, TEST/RESET, 3-light tester and then actual device. If something doesn't work you either have incorrect wiring or a bad GFCI/receptacle.
- If daisy-chaining: Turn off the breaker. Connect outgoing/load wires/cable to the outgoing/load side of the GFCI/breaker.
- Test thoroughly again. If it doesn't work, doesn't RESET, etc. then you have an *existing ground fault in the load wires/devices/receptacles* and will need to fix that before continuing.

Note that I didn't mention ground. That's because I assume you are using metal boxes with ground wires going to the boxes and the GFCI/receptacle grounding from the yoke to the box.

Note that on non-GFCI receptacles, neutral (line & load) is on one side and hot (line & load) is on the other side. With GFCI/receptacles you need to check carefully to see where each wire is supposed to connect. Connect things wrong and all kinds of strange things can happen. (Same advice applies to 3-way switches and smart switches.)